# Embedding problem for two algebraically closed fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Give two algebraically closed fields with same characteristic. Can we always embed one of them to the other?

I will appreciate any references.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, but the algebraic numbers can be embedded into $ \mathbb C $...

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, you are given *two* algebraically closed fields, and you are asked to embed one of them to another. You're not asked to provide embeddings in both directions, just one direction.

Comment: @DietrichBurde You're right that the question as it is stated is a bit confusing, but you may not even have an embedding of *sets* if you interpret it the way you did, let alone an embedding of fields, so I think my interpretation is what the OP meant.

Comment: @DietrichBurde FWIW I agree with the others. This may be somewhat idiomatic mathematical English, but I don't recall ever having seen a context where "one" used this way would not come with a tacitly implied freedom of choice. A shorthand for "one of them"

Comment: Use of "one" here is not unlike German "einer", for example (one of first Google hits) *Damit ist bewiesen, dass A zu einer der Zahlen a, a + 1, a + 2, ..., a + m − 1 kongruent ist". Choice is there (probably the correct parallel is between "one of" and "einer der". Anyway, I agree that non-trivial set theory must be used to answer the question. You probably need the axiom of choice to get the existence of transcendence bases needed in Starfall's argument. But, I believe in Zorn's lemma :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. If $ L $ and $ M $ are algebraically closed fields of the same characteristic, then let $ K $ be their common prime field; and pick transcendence bases $ S_L, S_M $ respectively. Without loss of generality, assume $ |S_L| \geq |S_M| $. Then, there is an injective map of *sets* $ S_M \to S_L $, which extends to an embedding $ K(S_M) \to K(S_L) \subset L $ of fields. $ M/K(S_M) $ is an algebraic extension and $ L $ is algebraically closed, thus the embedding $ K(S_M) \to L $ extends to an embedding $ M \to L $.